# как написать в одну строку преобразование

Tags: python

```
my_str = '3 43 34  453  45'

# переводим строку в список и вкладываем его в новую переменную

my_list = list(my_str)

# удаляем из списка пробелы

my_list = [i for i in my_list if i not in [' ']]

# переводим список из строк в список из чисел

my_list = [int(i) for i in my_list]
```

> [3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]

**подскажите пожалуйста как это преобразование произвести в одну строчку...** ну или просто более лаконично

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удаляем пробелы и конвертируем каждый символ в число:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in my_str.replace(" ", "")]
```

Если нужно удалять разные символов, то можно применить регулярные выражения:

```
import re
numbers =[int(i) for i in re.sub("[ 3]", "", my_str)]
```

В квадратных скобках символы, которые надо удалить, в данном случае пробел и "3".

Comment: спасибо. а если мне нужно не только пробел убрать но и цифру 3 к примеру, как это в replace добавить?

Comment: Например прицепить сзади ещё один: ``my_str.replace(" ", "").replace("3","")``

Comment: Добавил в ответ более компактный вариант.

Comment: re.sub("[ 3]", "", my_str)] - за что отвечают квадратные скобки в самом выражении "[ 3]", ведь нам нужно удалить только пробел и тройку.

Comment: @Jimmy это регулярное выражение означает любой из символов внутри скобок. Т.е. или пробел, или "3". Без скобок искалась бы последовательность " 3".

Answer (score 5):

```py
my_list = list(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, '3 43 34  453  45')))
```

Comment: сложновато, с мапами и методом isdigit не знаком пока :)

Comment: Красиво, однако )

Comment: лаконично и эффективно!

Comment: @Jimmy так же как и с генераторами списков, насколько я понимаю :)

Comment: генератор списка генерирует последовательность чисел, не знаю как в моей задаче они могли бы пригодиться

Comment: @Jimmy `[... for ...]` это генератор списка.

Comment: аа, я думал имеется ввиду range

Answer (score 4):

```
my_str = '3 43 34  453  45'
my_list = list(int(i) for i in my_str if i != ' ')
```

Comment: Выражение вида `list((a for a in b))` можно заменить на `[a for a in b]`, тогда результат работы генератора сразу помещается в список

Comment: Да, вы правы насчет лишней пары скобок. А по поводу list -  я люблю объявлять коллекции не скобками, а в явном виде через list, tuple, dict, set. Но может это мой личный фетиш :)

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант:

```
res = [int(i) for i in my_str if i.isdecimal() and i not in "35"]

print(res)
# [4, 4, 4, 4]
```